# What changed in Heroku-16 stack that made GDAL uninstallable in Python?

Tags: python, heroku, gdal

I am trying out [Heroku-16 stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-16-stack) and it seem's GDAL upgrade may need changes to the Python buildpack.

On cedar-14 i was using [cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack](https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack) and heroku's own [python buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python).

Same combination used on Heroku-16 — with the only change in gdal version  change in requirements to `gdal==2.1.3` — results in a build error: `No such file or directory: 'gdal-config'`

Do I need to change something in the way I build heroku slug or does build pack's need to be upgraded.

Any tips greatly appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-w_oq7nbx/gdal/setup.py", line 339, in <module>
    **extra )
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 280, in run
    self.find_sources()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 295, in find_sources
    mm.run()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 526, in run
    self.add_defaults()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 562, in add_defaults
    sdist.add_defaults(self)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/py36compat.py", line 36, in add_defaults
    self._add_defaults_ext()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/py36compat.py", line 119, in _add_defaults_ext
    build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-w_oq7nbx/gdal/setup.py", line 214, in finalize_options
    self.gdaldir = self.get_gdal_config('prefix')
  File "/tmp/pip-build-w_oq7nbx/gdal/setup.py", line 188, in get_gdal_config
    return fetch_config(option)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-w_oq7nbx/gdal/setup.py", line 135, in fetch_config
    raise gdal_config_error(e)
__main__.gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config'
```

Answer (score 5):

1. The Python buildpack way: 1.11.x works when using the **cedar-14 stack only**. If you set the environment variable: `BUILD_WITH_GEO_LIBRARIES=1` the Python buildpack knows to download GDAL, GEOS, and PROJ. GeoDjango seems to be able to find the libraries just fine in this case. This method downloads the libraries and binaries from an S3 bucket, which contains GDAL version 1.11.5.
2. The custom buildpack way: One of the more popular geo-enabled buildpacks is https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack. On the **cedar-14 stack** it works out of the box (remove the `BUILD_WITH_GEO_LIBRARIES`, purge your Heroku builder cache, redeploy).

   On the **heroku-16** stack, it doesn't correctly set up GDAL (explained below) nor environment variables for Django as of `a6f8e24`. Instead, you can use the fix (hopefully it will be merged eventually) in the buildpack at https://github.com/dschep/heroku-geo-buildpack. You'll need to set `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH` and `GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH` in your `settings.py` (you can use `os.getenv('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')`).

**Extended reading**:

When running the Python buildpack (or `a6f8e24` commit of the cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack buildpack) on the heroku-16 stack, libjasper.so is missing, so the GDAL library will not successfully load. Moreover, the `$PATH` variable in the Python buildpack is missing the vendor binaries, so `gdal-config` won't work out of the box.

**Appendix A - geo library versions installed**:

heroku-16: Using geos version: 3.6.1, Using gdal version: 2.1.3, Using proj version: 4.9.3

cedar-14: Using geos version: 3.4.2, Using gdal version: 1.11.1, Using proj version: 4.8.0_1

Comment: I just submitted a PR to the Python buildpack to take care of the libjasper issue. Hopefully it gets merged soon!

Comment: Any updates on this? I am still not able to run gdal binaries on heroku-16

Comment: My PR was merged (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/commit/002780c2d9c0ee300e71790a9025a32a26670c25) but I have no updates beyond that. Can you start a new question with additional details about exactly what issues you're having with logs + things and tag me in it or send me a private message? I'll take a look at it when I have some time.